# How to verify if Mule server is deployed or not?

Tags: mule

How to verify if Mule server is deployed or not? My intention is to send a query(HTTP or something else) to Mule server and to see if it is up or down. This I want to do when no applications are deployed on the Mule server. This is to do validation post Mule server deployment. I am using community edition v3.3.0 and v3.4.0. I cannot use Mule EE version.

Thanks and Regards
Jai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems like a good idea. 
The other option is to have you mule app sending a notification when started.

I know you said you can't use EE but the MMC module is probably what you need.

In any case they only problem with the previous approach is if you have a connectivity problem in the server you have your mule app running, but I reckon in that case you'll have several other problems.

HTH

Comment: Hi Dds: Thanks for the response but I don't have any app running on the ESB server which can send the events. I want to verify if Mule server is running or not with no apps on it.

Comment: Hi there, so short answer is no.
There is no out of the box notification module running on the ESB that's why MMC was created for.

I reckon you could build you own custom stuff but there is no such thing like after the ESB start it has an open port to validate its state sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever  hit the http we can see the response in console or in the logs.
First check whether your sever is running or not, give the proper url.